# What is different between @Mock and @Auto. ( Used for creating automatic mock object in JMock)?

Tags: mocking, jmock

Here is sample code to create mock objects automatically.

```
@Mock Mocked-class cheddar;
@Auto Sequence events;
```

Answer (score 0):

Not used @Auto yet. I use @Mock to create mock objects:

```
public class CommentCommandHandlerUnitTests {
    @Rule
    public final JUnitRuleMockery context = new JUnitRuleMockery();
    @Mock
    private Clock clock;

    .......
}
```

You need JUnitRuleMockery or @RunWith(JMock.class) to do the magic.

UPDATE:

According to the cookbook, @Auto is not used to create mock objects:

> To automagically create State and Sequence objects, annotate the
>   fields with @Auto. Again, jMock will initialise the field with a new
>   object named after the field before the test runs: